# TranslationY animation doesn't play with TransitionManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions

I have an issue with animations. I have defined two simple layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/two_hearts"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

looking like this:
[image: image in which a 2 of Hearts card appears in the upper left of a white background]

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/two_hearts"
        android:translationY="-60dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with looks:

[image: image in which the bottom portion of a 2 of Hearts card appears in the upper left of a white background]

The difference between them is `android:translationY="-60dp"`.

I switch between them in the GameFragment.kt:

```
class GameFragment: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var root: ConstraintLayout
    private var expanded = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_hidden, container, false) as ConstraintLayout
        root.setOnClickListener {
            show()
        }
        return root
    }

    private fun show() {
        if (expanded) {
            updateConstraints(R.layout.fragment_game_hidden)
        } else {
            updateConstraints(R.layout.fragment_game_shown)
        }
        expanded = !expanded
    }

    private fun updateConstraints(@LayoutRes id: Int) {
        val newConstraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        newConstraintSet.clone(context, id)
        val transition = ChangeBounds()
        transition.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        transition.duration = 1000
        newConstraintSet.applyTo(root)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transition)
    }

}
```

My problem is, the animation is not played at all, the card on the layout just jumps to target location without any transition. Why? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove android:translationY="-60dp" in : fragment_game_hidden.xml . Just use margin directly.

Try change to code below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/two_hearts"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, negative margin top causes the image to move up (with animation) but only to the top of the screen and no more. Not off the screen. It goes to 0 and then stops

Comment: hi@Jakub Lipowski ，So the animation problem is solved, you hope the image off the screen. Its easy . Just need to remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` , and use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` is fine.And i just updated my code,pls kindly refer.

Comment: Shirley is right. If you hope the image half off the screen, you could use app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  and app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"  at the same time .                          
Its a  question about how to use  ConstraintLayout.   If you dont be famliar about ConstraintLayout. You could use LinearLayout and  negative margin top  to realize it.

Comment: Using `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` indeed places the card half off the screen, but what if I need to place it, let's say, 2/3 off the screen? It's important as the rest of my app heavily relies of partially hidden images. I'm not sure if that's something to elaborate here or not, as it's not an animation issue anymore

Comment: hi@Jakub Lipowski ,I think the problem is solved. And now you're asking a new question. You'd better [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one.And It would be great to accept my answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks :)